# javascript exercise from the book ninja javascript

Tags: javascript, html, dom

This is example from one of the book(Ninja javascript).

I am not sure why console keep complaining that it cannot append to null..

```
        document.getElementById("results").appendChild(li);
```

is where I see the errors..  am I doing something wrong?

Entire code is below:

```
            <body>
    this.assert = function assert(value, desc) {
        var li = document.createElement("li");
        li.className = value ? "pass" : "fail";
        console.log("this is ", value);
        console.log("that is ", desc);
        console.log("that is ", li);
       // console.log("that is ", className);
        //console.log("that is ", results);
        li.appendChild(document.createTextNode(desc));
        document.getElementById("results").appendChild(li);

        if ( !value ) {
            li.parentNode.parentNode.className = "fail";
        }
        return li;
    };

    function useless(callback) {return callback(); }

    var text = "Domo Arigato!";
    assert(useless(function() {return text;}) === text,
           "The useless function works! " + text); 
</script>


<ul id="results"></ul>
```

UPDATE: after the suggestion works fine now.. thank you all

```
<script>
    window.onload = function () {
       function useless(callback) {return callback(); }

       var text = "Domo Arigato!";
       assert(useless(function() {return text;}) === text,
           "The useless function works! " + text); 

    }
</script>


<ul id="results"></ul>
```

UPDATE: just one more question,

```
assert(useless(function() {return text;}) === text,
```

Why is === text needed above? What purpose does it serve here??
(I just tested and without === text, it also works.. so what was the intention of the author here?)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's because your script executed before the element with `id` of `results` existed on the page.

You can:

- Place the script after it
- Execute your script during the `window.onload` event
- A more appropriate event is the [`DOMContentLoaded`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Reference/Events/DOMContentLoaded) event

Comment: There's also no opening to the <script> tag.

Comment: @krillgar But the error mentioned seems to suggest the script did run.

Comment: Agreed. But that should still be fixed. I'm kind of surprised that it did run, but javascript lets so many of those things go.

Comment: sorry beginning script was omitted by myself by mistake for pasting here. Trynig the suggestion now.

Comment: @krillgar A missing `<script>` tag is definitely not one of those things that JavaScript would let slide.

Comment: @JLRishe I wouldn't have thought so. I've never tried, and even though I'm on the internet I'm not going to start a debate. But, yeah, the browser wouldn't know what to do when it got there, and probably just displayed it as text on the page, correct